# Recover translation in Matlab Using Automated Feature Matching

Tags: matlab, translation

This example shows how to Find Image Rotation and Scale Using Automated Feature Matching
[webpage](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/find-image-rotation-and-scale-using-automated-feature-matching.html?refresh=true)

Matlab uses SURF to recover rotation and scaling between two images (original and distorted)

In step 5, it said tx and ty are x and y translations in Tinv matrix. I run the code and found these two values are not close to 0 but actually there is no translation has been applied from original image to distorted image and only rotation and scaling have been applied in this case.

I can some kind of understand the reason why we get tx and ty with large values. in this example it is because poses are calculated based on all features rather than the center point, but my question is can we accurate estimate translation? For example, in this case, tx and ty should be very small values since the whole image is not translated based on the center.

Answer (score 0):

I'm away from MATLAB at the moment, but I believe there is a subtle issue at play here is that the imrotate step used to apply rotation to the image synthetically is actually rotating about the center of the image, instead of about the origin, which is what the linear part of the affine matrix does. I believe because of this there in fact is a non-zero translation involved between the moving and fixed images.

If you implement the equivalent rotation about the image center operation as an affine tranformation, this can be done in three parts: 1) Translate the image so that it is centered at the origin (0,0). 2) Rotate the image by theta. 3) Translate the image so that the center of the image is where it started.